# Storing data in servlet response

Tags: jsp, servlets, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using spring. I want that when user is authenticated server should response all users related data (e.g name,city, country,about,emails,address,...) from within `AuthenticationSuccessHandler`.

I was thinking of storing user data object as session attribute and then iterate it in JSP. Will it be a good approach ? I am confuse with the size of data that can be stored as session attribute.

I want to do this to save one unnecessary HTTP request using AJAX. In the above approach in one request i can do validation and return data.

Comment: Why store it in session unless you actually need it everywhere?

Comment: shall i make a separate ajax request for this?isn't it possible in one shot as i described?

Comment: Do you need it everywhere? Maybe a custom `UserDetails` is what you are looking for?

Comment: no i need it only on user profile page

Comment: Just add the details to the `ModelMap` and display them in your JSP. Use the `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` to get a hold on the authentication object.